# Does anyone knows how to make a load balancer for tensorflow-serving in ECS?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ecs, tensorflow-serving

I tried to load balance a tensorflow serving task with ELB but it keeps failing, I also added a health check endpoint but it doesnt work and the task keeps dying. I'm also using both REST and gRPC services in my task. Does anyone has an idea of what could make it work.

Comment: Can you take a look at this [blog](https://techblog.realtor.com/building-tensorflow-serving-aws-gpu-instances/) which has a detailed steps on hosting TF serving model in AWS ECS. Thanks!